# I have no particle systems in my menu options

Tags: particles

[image: my menu]

I am new to Blender. I have no *Particle Systems* in my menu options.

Is it an add-on I need to download or is there something I need to purchase?

Comment: You can convert a curve to a mesh with Alt+C.  After converting to a mesh you can add a particle system.

Comment: You don't need to purchase any native functionality, Blender is Free and Open Source. Please use descriptive titles for your questions

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't add particle systems to curves. Try another mesh. Cube for example.

Comment: Also they can convert the curve to a mesh by using Alt + C

Comment: I created a mesh cube and i still couldn't add particles. :\